# Piping output from ffmpeg/avconv over ssh to a file

Tags: linux, ssh, video, ffmpeg, libav

I like to pipe the output from ffmpeg/avconv over ssh to a file. I would like to do something like this.

```
ssh USER_NAME@SERVER_IP "avconv -i "http://svtplay20k-f.akamaihd.net/i/se/open/20141013/1368164-001A/EPISOD-1368164-001A-c49ff75135a27611_,144,252,360,468,892,1584,2700,.mp4.csmil/index_6_av.m3u8?null=" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -bsf aac_adtstoasc -f mp4 pipe:1" | cat > pipeOutput.mp4
```

I have tried above but get `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted`

I tried changing to `-f avi` and `pipeOutput.avi`. That gave me a very large but not working file.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ffmpeg to write to an MP4 file, it needs the output to be seekable (for creating the required MP4 atoms). MP4 is not a streamable container though. This means you cannot pipe "raw" MP4 data over an SSH connection, or just a regular Unix pipe.

You could use Matroska as a format:

```
ssh USER_NAME@SERVER_IP "ffmpeg -i "..." -c copy -f matroska pipe:1" | cat > out.mkv
```

Or use MPEG-2 Transport Streams, but they require filtering of the MP4 bitstream to an H.264 Annex B bytestream that can be packetized:

```
ssh USER_NAME@SERVER_IP "ffmpeg -i "..." -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts pipe:1" | cat > out.ts
```

Note: I used `ffmpeg` here since I cannot test `avconv`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both approaches. The first one (MKV) worked without any issues. The second one (MPEG-2) gave an error message. `h264_mp4toannexb failed for stream 0, codec copy: Invalid argument`. Maybe it is the result of using `avconv`.

Comment: Hm. In the [avconv manual](https://libav.org/avconv.html) it is listed as example, so I don't know what exactly goes wrong. But I don't use avconv… :)